# Why is the Erlang compiler saying that my clause evaluates to false?

Tags: if-statement, erlang

When I try to compile the following code:

```
score(_X) -> mysqrt = math:sqrt(_X),
  if
    mysqrt < 100.0 -> true;
    true -> 0
  end.
```

The compiler says:

src/leap.erl:16: the guard for this clause evaluates to 'false'

I think I am assigning a variable `mysqrt` and then checking its result, which does not necessarily have to be less than `100.0.`  Evidently that is not what is happening.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Erlang, variable names begin with a capital letter or an underscore.  In your code, `mysqrt` is *not* a variable, but an atom.

The line `mysqrt = math:sqrt(_X)` is thus an *assertion* that the return value of `math:sqrt` is equal to this atom, which will fail because that function returns a floating point number - but the compiler doesn't know this.

Then you compare `mysqrt` to `100.0`.  In Erlang, numbers always compare as less than atoms, so `mysqrt < 100.0` is always false - this is what the compiler is warning you about.

Call your variable `MySqrt` instead, and your code should work.

(Also, the convention is to use variable names starting with an underscore only when the variable is not used, as such names suppress "unused variable" warnings from the compiler.  It would be more idiomatic to just call the argument to this function `X` instead of `_X`.)